# Text based game won't output what's desired

Tags: python, dictionary

The code keeps reading the room wrong and outputting unexpected result. The code also doesn't accept the exit condition

When I input West, it accurately says I'm in the south hall, but when I go to move to the East, it reads as Locker room instead of Entrance. the same happens when I go to the North, it says invalid move. Below is the code I currently have

```
rooms = {
        'Entrance': {'East': 'Locker Room', 'West': 'South Hall'},
        'Locker Room': {'West': 'Entrance'},
        'South Hall': {'North': 'Main Room', 'East': 'Entrance'},
        'Main Room': {'East': 'Power Grid', 'South': 'South Hall'},
        'Power Grid': {'West': 'Main Room', 'East': 'Restroom', 'North': 'North Hall'},
        'North Hall': {'South': 'Power Grid', 'West': 'Control Room', 'East': 'Loading Bay'},
        'Control Room': {'East': 'North Hall'},
        'Loading Bay': {'West': 'North Hall'}
    }

room = 'Entrance'

print('You must hurry to save your friends!')
print('You are in the Entrance \nWhere would you like to go?')

move = input()
possible_moves = rooms[room]


while move in possible_moves:
        room = possible_moves[move]
        print('You are in the', room, '\nWhere would you like to go?')
        move = input()
else:
        print(f"{move} isn't something you can do from the {room}")
```

Comment: You're only updating `room` in the loop, you're not updating `possible_moves`…

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `possible_moves` value each time you `move`.

Here is a fixed version of your code :

```
rooms = {
        'Entrance': {'East': 'Locker Room', 'West': 'South Hall'},
        'Locker Room': {'West': 'Entrance'},
        'South Hall': {'North': 'Main Room', 'East': 'Entrance'},
        'Main Room': {'East': 'Power Grid', 'South': 'South Hall'},
        'Power Grid': {'West': 'Main Room', 'East': 'Restroom', 'North': 'North Hall'},
        'North Hall': {'South': 'Power Grid', 'West': 'Control Room', 'East': 'Loading Bay'},
        'Control Room': {'East': 'North Hall'},
        'Loading Bay': {'West': 'North Hall'}
    }

room = 'Entrance'

print('You must hurry to save your friends!')
print('You are in the Entrance \nWhere would you like to go?')

move = input()
possible_moves = rooms[room]


while move in possible_moves:
        room = possible_moves[move]
        # update possible_moves
        possible_moves = rooms[room]
        print('You are in the', room, '\nWhere would you like to go?')
        move = input()
else:
        print(f"{move} isn't something you can do from the {room}")
```